# MPI: Why does my MPICH program fails for large no. of processes?

Tags: mpi, mpich

```
/* C Example */
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int rank, size;
  int buffer_length = MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME;
  char hostname[buffer_length];

  MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);      /* starts MPI */
  MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);        /* get current process id */
  MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);        /* get number of processes */

  MPI_Get_processor_name(hostname, &buffer_length); /* get hostname */

  printf( "Hello world from process %d running on %s of %d\n", rank, hostname, size );
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

The above program compiles and run successfully on ubuntu 12.04 for smaller no. of processes. But it fails when I try to execute with 1000s of processes. Why it is so? 
I am expecting that scheduler would keep the threads in queue and can dispatch one by one (I am running this code on a single core machine)

Why the following error is coming for large no. of processes and how to resolve this issue?

```
root@ubuntu:/home# mpiexec -n 1000 ./hello
[proxy:0:0@ubuntu] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:26): pipe error (Too many open files)
[proxy:0:0@ubuntu] launch_procs (./pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:751): create process returned error
[proxy:0:0@ubuntu] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (./pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:935): launch_procs returned error
[proxy:0:0@ubuntu] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (./tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:0@ubuntu] main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:226): demux engine error waiting for event
Killed
```

Answer (score 3):

You are running into the open file limit on your system. Default in Ubuntu is 1024. You can try raising the limit in your session with the ulimit command.

```
ulimit -n 2048
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how the limit on open files is related to number of process that can be launched?

Comment: Well for starters, running 1000 processes means opening the program file 1000 times. Plus there are other libraries and such that the program needs to execute, so you can see how they would quickly add up for that many processes.